# How to display images in Django 1.10

Tags: python, django

i am not good in django, i use Django 1.10 and now i have problem with image displaying. I read in this version some stuff has changed but i don't get it. Here is what i have now:

settings.py:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/templates')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR, ]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/Users/john/myprojects/goal/website/goal/media/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Maybe something is unusual here and i can delete it?

template:

```
{% block content%}
    {{ car.name }}
    {{ car.photo.url }}
{% endblock %}
```

Here is folder where i have my images:

> C:/Users/john/myprojects/goal/website/goal/media/images

And what i see instead of image on my website:

> /media/images/mynewcar.jpg

What must i change?

i pasted to urls.py:

> media_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(**file**),'media')

and to urlpatterns

> url(r'^media/(.*)$','django.views.static.serve',{'document_root':
>   media_dir}),

Comment: you have no `<img>` tag in your template

Answer (score 4):

You have to put `<img>` tag

```
{% block content%}
    {{ car.name }}
    <img src="{{ car.photo.url }}">
{% endblock %}
```

**Update**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: That's true, thank you - now i see place for image but there is not. When i click show image i get information 'Page not found'. How should i change url or something like that? Is my path to folder wrong?

Comment: Did you add media url in uls.py in dev mode ?

Comment: i edited my first post and i added what i have in urls file, but now i get information that view must be a callable  or a list/tuple in the case of include(). I tried to change urlpattern to url(r'^media/(.*)$',static.serve,{'document_root': media_dir}), but then i get ''function' object has no attribute 'serve'